# using CSVloader in java

Tags: java, matlab, csv

i'm trying to convert a .csv file into a .arff file, but i seem to have an error in loading the csv file.

I created the csv file by using this matlab code:
[image: matlab code]

and here is the csv file output:
[image: csvfile]

now, i'm using this java code to load the csv for conversion:
[image]

and now i'm getting this error:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you have a non-conformity in your CSV file. In other words, you do not have a CSV file actually.

Tip: Try using in Excel -> Export -> CSV File and do the load by Java Code again.